# Convert date formatted string to DateTime object?

Tags: twig

I need to convert a date formatted string to a `datetime` object so that I can use the Twig `date()` function on the datetime object.

Example string: `'2015-06-20'`

Can Twig accomplish this or perhaps could it be done with a custom Twig extension?

Answer (score 6):

you can do this

```
{{ "12/14/2016"|date("Y-m-d", option_timezone_convert) }}
```

be aware, it will create from that string a datetime object with the default timezone, if you apply a timezone option, it will convert it.

Comment: Are you sure this creates a `DateTime`? I always receive a string rather than a DateTime object. Usually the function `{% set dateTime = date('2015-06-20') %}` does that. You can then use the `format` function `{{ dateTime.format('d.m.Y') }}`

Comment: the string passed directly to date filter will get the string into datetime object, then using the timezone to apply over the date, then back to string to use in Twig. He said he has a string that needs to convert to datetime, and then to use twig to print it

Comment: Yes but you won't ever have access to that `DateTime` object in twig, instead you only receive the string. For example you can't use the `date.modify` function

Comment: nonetheless it will convert that string and display it to correct timezone, it will actually correct the date there.

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html please see the docs, it will clearly show there what I am saying

Comment: I read the docs "The date filter formats a date to a given format" thus it will return a string rather than a DateTime. When I dump the result of the `|date` filter I always receive a string as well instead of a DateTime. It won't return a DateTime object as you said - no matter what

Comment: It will return a string, but before that it will apply requested timezone, from UTC, not directly deffault

Answer (score -1):

You can use [date function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/date.html) (here in in conjunction with [date filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html) to display a formatted date)  :

```
{{ date('2015-06-20')|date('d/m/Y') }}
```

Twigfiddle : https://twigfiddle.com/qejgfd

Answer (score -8):

PHP's DateTime object can do this as a constructor:

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-06-20');
```

Comment: the Op is looking for the solution using twig